# Copying a range of columns from a text file and creating a new file

Tags: python, parsing, text-files

I am new to Python and I am doing some data parsing for some sonar files that have more info than I need to process the data. I have found this code and I am trying to manipulate it to meet my goal. I only need the first 53 columns of info the last 100+ columns are extraneous data that is not needed.

```
f = open("ADV125cm.txt", "r")
g = open("ADV125cm_fixed.txt", "w")

for line in f:
    if line.strip():
        g.write("\t".join(line.split(0,53)[1:]) + "\n")
f.close()
g.close()
```

I got this error code and I have no idea what it means:

> TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Any help is better than no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `TypeError: expected a character buffer object` because [string.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) expects a string of chars to be stripped. You are passing `0, 53`. Probably you get confused with the slice operation. If you want to get the first 53 *columns* of a line you need `line[:53]`. Applying this change your `for` loop code becomes:

```
for line in f:
    if line.strip():
        g.write("\t".join(line[:53]) + "\n")
```

However if what you want are the first 53 *columns* of every line with the leading and trailing whitespace characters stripped, the code could be refactored like this:

```
for line in f:
    g.write(line.strip()[:53] + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in how .split() is used. I don't have the files so i can't be sure, but that's not a correct usage. The way to do it is:

```
f = open("ADV125cm.txt", "r")
g = open("ADV125cm_fixed.txt", "w")

for line in f:
    if line.strip():
        g.write(line[:52]+ "\n")
f.close()
g.close()
```